# Где орфограмма на безударную гласную?

Tags: общие-вопросы, лексикография, однокоренные-слова

Такой сложный вопрос оказался почему-то для нас. Помогите разобраться.

В каком слове содержатся две орфограммы: правописание проверяемой
безударной гласной в корне и правописание непроизносимой согласной?

Выберите правильный вариант ответа:
1) доблестный
2) корыстный
3) сказка
4) площадь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется, нет такого слова. Непроизносимые согласные в словах 1) доблестный 2) корыстный, но они содержат непроверяемые гласные в корне.

КорЫсть - ударение на Ы, этимологический родственник корнать (сдирать), так что дословно то, что можно "содрать" и присвоить. Также: кора, короткий, кОроб.

Доблесть - этимологический суффикс ЕСТЬ, от добль - храбрый, в родственных отношениях со словом "добрый", оба от "доба" - пора расцвета и зрелости.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Ребёнок не смог найти, и я также не вижу. Но это задание для 3 класса и вариант обязателен 1 из 4.

Comment: Наверное, составители считают, что есть слово кОрысть, учитывая, что все орфоэпические словари строго предупреждают: такое ударение встречается, но так говорить категорически нельзя.

Comment: Словарь Русское словесное ударение.**Словарь нарицательных имён**.(на Грамота.ру)
Автор М. В. Зарва.
Печатное издание М.: ЭНАС, 2001.,  рекомендует только один вариант: ''кор**ы**сть''(не к**о**рысть). А какие орфоэпические словари вы имели в виду?

Comment: Разумеется, все словари предлагают форму "корЫсть". Я же имею в виду тех составителей вопросов, которые предлагают в обязательном порядке найти проверяемую гласную. Может быть, они неправильно ставят ударение в этом слове.

Comment: Вера, даже если наряду с ударением на втором слоге было бы и ударение и на первом слоге, все равно задание некорректно. Поскольку проверяемую гласную находят, подобрав такое однокоренное слово или родственное слово, где безударное гласная будет под ударением. Такого слова нет. Вероятное, составители или ошиблись, или имели в виду непроверяемую безударную гласную. Ну ладно, ошиблись составители, а педагог куда смотрит?

Comment: Педагог не смотрит. Это задание из обнинских общероссийских олимпиад, весенний тур.Со всеми дочь справилась, а это "заколдованное" и выяснить у них не могу.Это общероссийский уровень платных олимпиад.

Comment: Но ведь на олимпиаду посылает школа, пусть они разберутся. В олимпиадах тоже встречаются ошибки.

Comment: А если непроверяемая гласная, тогда и в доблести е невозможно проверить, ведь на сегодня е уже входит в корень, так размышляют о составе этого слова. 
И вот нашла в словарных словах 8 класса слово бескорыстный.Это тоже как доказательство буквы о или нет. совсем тупик

Comment: Можно найти и другие слова: Корыстный — бескорыстный;
корыстно — бескорыстно;
корыстность — бескорыстность;
корыстолюбивый — бескорыстный';
корыстолюбие — бескорыстие

Comment: О во всех случаях безударное.

Comment: Нет, не школа. Это лично наше решение и свободное участие. Я уже думала может имели в виду -блест- в слове доблестный и отсутствие суффикса а, но нет чередования с буквой и.